# Confusion Matrix looks weird

Tags: python, deep-learning, confusion-matrix

I am running a deep learning code that prints out a confusion matrix for 100 subjects. When I print the matrix, it looks like this

[image]

How can I adjust the confusion matrix to look more "Bigger" to be able to fit all 100 subjects on the sides and also to see the misses?

Below is the python code which shows the confusion matrix included:

```
    # Importing libraries
import os
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
import numpy as np
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from image_dataset_loader import load
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

np.random.seed(1000)

# Instantiation
AlexNet = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(227, 227, 3), kernel_size=(11, 11), strides=(4, 4), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
AlexNet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
AlexNet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
AlexNet.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
AlexNet.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

# Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
AlexNet.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(32, 32, 3,)))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
AlexNet.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(4096))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))

# Add Dropout
AlexNet.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(1000))
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
AlexNet.add(Dropout(0.4))

# Output Layer
AlexNet.add(Dense(100)) #LFW-CARE
#AlexNet.add(Dense(24)) #FERET
AlexNet.add(BatchNormalization())
AlexNet.add(Activation('softmax'))

# Model Summary
AlexNet.summary()

# Compiling the model
AlexNet.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Josh Plan 1: FERET Pathway
#path = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_FERET/Plan1-DL/Images_AlexNet"
#imgPath = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_FERET/Plan1-DL/Images_AlexNet/Josh_Training_CHD_8I_24S_227"
#testPath = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_FERET/Plan1-DL/Images_AlexNet/Josh_Testing_CHD_24S_227"

#LFW-CARE Pathway
path = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_LFW-CARE/Plan1-DL-LFW-CARE"
imgPath = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_LFW-CARE/Plan1-DL-LFW-CARE/Josh_Training_SEN_8I_100S_227"
testPath = "C:/Users/JoshG/PycharmProjects/Local-Binary-Patterns/Images_LFW-CARE/Plan1-DL-LFW-CARE/Josh_Testing_SEN_100S_227"
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = load(path, [imgPath, testPath])


temp = []
for label in y_train:
    temp.append([label])
y_train = np.array(temp)
# print('-------------------------4')
# print(y_train)
temp = []
for label in y_test:
    temp.append([label])
y_test = np.array(temp)

# Train-validation-test split
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=.12)

# Dimension of the CIFAR10 dataset
print((x_train.shape, y_train.shape))
print((x_val.shape, y_val.shape))
print((x_test.shape, y_test.shape))

# Onehot Encoding the labels.
# from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels

# Since we have 10 classes we should expect the shape[1] of y_train,y_val and y_test to change from 1 to 10
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_val = to_categorical(y_val)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

# Verifying the dimension after one hot encoding
print((x_train.shape, y_train.shape))
print((x_val.shape, y_val.shape))
print((x_test.shape, y_test.shape))

# Image Data Augmentation
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)
val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)

# Fitting the augmentation defined above to the data
train_generator.fit(x_train)
val_generator.fit(x_val)
test_generator.fit(x_test)

# Learning Rate Annealer
lrr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_accuracy', factor=.01, patience=3, min_lr=1e-5)

# Defining the parameters
batch_size = 10
epochs = 50
learn_rate = .001

# Training the model
AlexNet.fit(train_generator.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
            epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
            validation_data=val_generator.flow(x_val, y_val, batch_size=batch_size),
            validation_steps=2, callbacks=[lrr], verbose=1)

# After successful training, we will visualize its performance.

# Plotting the training and validation loss
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)  # Creates 2 subplots under 1 column

# Assigning the first subplot to graph training loss and validation loss
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['loss'], color='b', label='Training Loss')
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['val_loss'], color='r', label='Validation Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)  # Creates 2 subplots under 1 column

# Plotting the training accuracy and validation accuracy
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['accuracy'], color='b', label='Training Accuracy')
ax.plot(AlexNet.history.history['val_accuracy'], color='r', label='Validation Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


# Defining function for confusion matrix plot
def plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title=None,
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues):
    if not title:
        if normalize:
            title = 'Normalized confusion matrix'
        else:
            title = 'Confusion matrix, without normalization'

    # Compute confusion matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    # Print Confusion matrix
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
    im = ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set(xticks=np.arange(cm.shape[1]),
           yticks=np.arange(cm.shape[0]),
           xticklabels=classes, yticklabels=classes,
           title=title,
           ylabel='True label',
           xlabel='Predicted label')

    # Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
             rotation_mode="anchor")
    # Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i in range(cm.shape[0]):
        for j in range(cm.shape[1]):
            ax.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                    ha="center", color="white"
                if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
    plt.tight_layout()
    return ax


np.set_printoptions(precision=2)

# Making prediction
y_pred = (AlexNet.predict_classes(x_test))
y_true = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
print(y_pred)
print(y_pred.shape)

# Plotting the confusion matrix
confusion_mtx = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

# class_names=['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 'truck']
CLASS_NAMES = [f.name for f in os.scandir(imgPath) if f.is_dir()]
class_names = CLASS_NAMES
print(class_names)

print("ypred\n", y_pred)
print("ytrue", y_true)

# Plotting non-normalized confusion matrix
plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes=class_names, title='AlexNet Confusion matrix, without normalization')
plt.show()

# Plotting normalized confusion matrix
# plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes=class_names, normalize=True, title='Normalized confusion matrix')
# plt.show()

# Classification Metrics
acc_score = accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
print('\n\n\t\t  Accuracy Score: ', str(round((100 * acc_score), 2)), '%')
prec_score = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
print('   Precision Score Macro: ', str(round((100 * prec_score), 2)), '%')
prec_score = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
print('   Precision Score Micro: ', str(round((100 * prec_score), 2)), '%')
prec_score = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
print('Precision Score Weighted: ', str(round((100 * prec_score), 2)), '%')
rec_score = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
print('\t\t\tRecall Macro: ', str(round((100 * rec_score), 2)), '%')
rec_score = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
print('\t\t\tRecall Micro: ', str(round((100 * rec_score), 2)), '%')
rec_score = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
print('\t\t Recall Weighted: ', str(round((100 * rec_score), 2)), '%')
f_score = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
print('\t\t  F1 Score Macro: ', str(round((100 * f_score), 2)), '%')
f_score = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
print('\t\t  F1 Score Micro: ', str(round((100 * f_score), 2)), '%')
f_score = f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='weighted')
print('\t   F1 Score Weighted: ', str(round((100 * f_score), 2)), '%')
```

Comment: can you please share the code you have tried so far ?

Comment: @dassum - Sorry about that. Code has been added.

Answer (score 2):

In your `plot_confusion_matrix()` function, you included a line

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
```

You can adjust the figsize values `x` and `y` so that everything is readable.

Also, if you only want to print misclassified classes, you could adjust your plot function with something like the following:

```
def plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, classes,
                          normalize=False,
                          title=None,
                          cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                          only_misses = True): # Add only_misses to function definition
    if not title:
        if normalize:
            title = 'Normalized confusion matrix'
        else:
            title = 'Confusion matrix, without normalization'

    # Compute confusion matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

    ##### NEW CODE #####
    # Print only misclassified classes
    if only_misses:
        cm_missed = []
        classes_missed = []
        for i, arr in enumerate(cm):
            if cm[i,i] != sum(arr):
                cm_missed.append(arr.tolist())
                classes_missed.append(classes[i])
        cm = np.asarray(cm_missed)
        classes = classes_missed
    ##### NEW CODE END #####

    if normalize:
        cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized confusion matrix")
    else:
        print('Confusion matrix, without normalization')

    # Print Confusion matrix
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))
    im = ax.imshow(cm, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
    # We want to show all ticks...
    ax.set(xticks=np.arange(cm.shape[1]),
           yticks=np.arange(cm.shape[0]),
           xticklabels=classes, yticklabels=classes,
           title=title,
           ylabel='True label',
           xlabel='Predicted label')

    # Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
             rotation_mode="anchor")
    # Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
    fmt = '.2f' if normalize else 'd'
    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i in range(cm.shape[0]):
        for j in range(cm.shape[1]):
            ax.text(j, i, format(cm[i, j], fmt),
                    ha="center", color="white"
                if cm[i, j] > thresh else "black")
    plt.tight_layout()
    return ax
```

Comment: For some reason, it is not working out. How can I just display the missed labels (False positive and false negatives) to show in the console/terminal?

Comment: I just noticed that you do have
```fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))``` in your confusion matrix function, so you can try and adjust those values.

Comment: So I adjusted that, it did fix it but due to being 100 subjects, it doesn't fit my screen to show properly. Where do I add or adjust the code to display the missed within the run/terminal/console section?

Comment: I have edited my answer with a solution for that!

Comment: For some reason, I updated the code to your recommendation and got this error message:

Comment: I updated the code and got this error message: 

ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (72), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (100).

Comment: I updated the code once again, maybe it is because of the length of the class names... Try and play around with it...